# PowerShell try/catch/finally

Tags: powershell, try-catch, block

I recently wrote a PowerShell script that works great - however, I'd like to now upgrade the script and add some error checking / handling - but I've been stumped at the first hurdle it seems. Why won't the following code work?

```
try {
  Remove-Item "C:\somenonexistentfolder\file.txt" -ErrorAction Stop
}

catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
  "item not found"
}

catch {
  "any other undefined errors"
  $error[0]
}

finally {
  "Finished"
}
```

The error is caught in the second catch block - you can see the output from `$error[0]`. Obviously I would like to catch it in the first block. What am I missing?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`-ErrorAction Stop` is changing things for you.  Try adding this and see what you get:

```
Catch [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException] {
"caught a StopExecution Exception" 
$error[0]
}
```

Comment: That's pretty interesting, considering `$_.Exception` is an `ItemNotFoundException` and not an `ActionPreferencesStopException`. I bet the latter drives from `RuntimeException`.

Comment: I think you're right.  I like your switch version.  More in line with what steve is trying to do.

Comment: Right, the trouble here is that it is a non-terminating error.  So even though it is a `ItemNotFoundException`, it isn't actually getting thrown unless wrapped in a `ActionPreferencesStopException`.  As a developer, this annoys me.  :)

Comment: @JasonMArcher Seems like a bug in an older version. This is working for me as expected in Powershell 5.0 That is it catches the `ItemNotFoundException`

Comment: @JasonS Yay, it looks like you no longer have to worry about the exception getting wrapped.

Answer (score 31):

That is very odd.

I went through `ItemNotFoundException`'s base classes and tested the following multiple `catch`es to see what **would** catch it:

```
try {
  remove-item C:\nonexistent\file.txt -erroraction stop
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
  write-host 'ItemNotFound'
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.SessionStateException] {
  write-host 'SessionState'
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException] {
  write-host 'RuntimeException'
}
catch [System.SystemException] {
  write-host 'SystemException'
}
catch [System.Exception] {
  write-host 'Exception'
}
catch {
  write-host 'well, darn'
}
```

As it turns out, the output was `'RuntimeException'`. I also tried it with a different exception `CommandNotFoundException`:

```
try {
  do-nonexistent-command
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException] {
  write-host 'CommandNotFoundException'
}
catch {
  write-host 'well, darn'
}
```

That output `'CommandNotFoundException'` correctly.

I vaguely remember reading elsewhere (though I couldn't find it again) of problems with this. In such cases where exception filtering didn't work correctly, they would catch the closest `Type` they could and then use a `switch`. The following just catches `Exception` instead of `RuntimeException`, but is the `switch` equivalent of my first example that checks all base types of `ItemNotFoundException`:

```
try {
  Remove-Item C:\nonexistent\file.txt -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [System.Exception] {
  switch($_.Exception.GetType().FullName) {
    'System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException' {
      write-host 'ItemNotFound'
    }
    'System.Management.Automation.SessionStateException' {
      write-host 'SessionState'
    }
    'System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException' {
      write-host 'RuntimeException'
    }
    'System.SystemException' {
      write-host 'SystemException'
    }
    'System.Exception' {
      write-host 'Exception'
    }
    default {'well, darn'}
  }
}
```

This writes `'ItemNotFound'`, as it should.