# PowerShell Multiple Catch Issue

Tags: powershell

I'm following [Microsoft examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6) and I get an error when I run this in PowerShell (5.1). I am unable to repro this in the ISE.

```
$app="notepad2354.exe"
try{
   iex $app
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException]{
   write-host 'ERROR! The app file could not be found.'
}
catch {
   write-host 'ERROR! Unknown error when executing the step. Error: ' + $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Error:

> catch : The term 'catch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

The odd thing is it works fine on the first catch. If I switch the order, the second one always fails with this message.  Any ideas why this is error'ing?

Comment: That syntax seems to work, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779186/powershell-try-catch-finally). I'm not able to reproduce on Powershell v4. What Powershell version are you on?

Comment: my setup = win7, ps5.1 ///// i DO NOT get that error when the general catch is 1st - i get `Catch block must be the last catch block.` - which is what one would expect since the generic catch is for "none of the previous ones matched". ///// i suspect you have a typo OR an invalid character in there that is making PoSh think the `catch` is not matching up with a previous `try`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I literally copied the text from my question and I get an error on the second catch

Comment: what version of PoSh are you running?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey 5.1.14393.2879

Comment: i am lost. [*sigh ...*] your code - copy-pasted into my ISE window - runs correctly. when i reverse the two `catch` blocks, the error i get is `Catch block must be the last catch block.` - as expected.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Figured out the problem. It was mostly user error. This is the first thing I haven't been able to simply paste into a PowerShell window and run.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - thanks for posting the fix ... i still don't understand the WHY of it ... but you got it working and that is the prime concern. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I figured it out, it is because of `PSReadline`. See my Answer post below.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - oh. my. goodness ... thank you for calling that to my attention! [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to @UnhandledExcepSean answer where he saw that his issue is with Copy\Pasting into PowerShell console.

The root issue is that `PSReadline` changed the right-click pasting functionality.

[PSReadline](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine), originally offered as an installable module for PowerShell v3 and v4, now comes default with PowerShell v5+ and PowerShell Core 6+. It is a nice module that adds a bunch of new things like syntax highlighting, better multi-line editing experience, etc.

When `PSReadline` is imported, Right-Click pasting doesn't "work" as expected see GitHub issue: [Right click paste should work mostly like Ctrl+v paste 579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/579). What happens is in:

> PSReadLine, if the input is "complete", as in, it parses without an
>   IncompleteParseException, then the input will be accepted...
>
> [https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/579#issuecomment-345824783]

Basically, the Right-Click pasting comes from the Windows PowerShell terminal "GUI" host, and streams in the characters into the PowerShell console, where they are being intercepted and interpreted by `PSReadline` to provide things like syntax highlighting. As it streams in, the trailing `}` curly brace + newline, completes the statement, and it executes. The second `catch` statement on the new line then errors out because it is, indeed, on it's own not correct.

Instead, if you use `Ctrl+V` to paste, the above Copy/Pasting of code **does** work. the `Ctrl+V` functionality delivers the entire clipboard contents at once to `PSReadline`, which interprets everything as a whole before continuing with the execution.

You don't see this happen PowerShell ISE or scripts because Right-Click Pasting doesn't happen.

For fun, you can remove `PSReadline` in your PowerShell console session:

```
Remove-Module PSReadline
```

And then see that Right-Click paste now works as "expected".... Although all the goodness of `PSReadline` are also gone :-(

Since the Right-Click functionality is specifically a Windows PowerShell terminal issue, even if `PSReadline` wanted to intercept the Right-Click mouse-hook, it would require `PSReadline` to now use Windows specific API's to emulate the Windows clipboard feature. This go against "Core" cross-platform functionality. This means that this Right-Click anomaly will likely persist with `Ctrl+V` to paste as the <s>only</s> recommended way to paste.

Answer (score 1):

Your type-specific catches should always come before your catch-all, so expect an error if you switch the order of the catches above. However, the error you're getting is not what I'd expect, so I can only assume you've got a syntax typo somewhere. The only way I can repro this is if I execute a catch block without a try in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that I can't simply copy and paste that script into a PowerShell command window. It works in the ISE and, as I just found out, it works  inside a Powershell Script file.

My guess is that it processes the try..catch as a batch and doesn't read the entire pasted command before executing. You can work around this issue by making sure the second catch is on the same line as the first catch ends, like so:

```
$app="notepad2354.exe"
try{
   iex $app
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException]{
   write-host 'ERROR! The app file could not be found.'
} catch {
   write-host 'ERROR! Unknown error when executing the step. Error: ' + $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that came across the same issue, using visual studio code and bypassing pasting in a PS editor (working from a file). I suppose the pasting error wasn't applicable to my error.
What seemed to help for me, is changing how I format my code.
To use the code from the example, changed to how it works for me:

```
$app="notepad2354.exe"
try{
   iex $app
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException]{
   write-host 'ERROR! The app file could not be found.'
} catch {
   write-host 'ERROR! Unknown error when executing the step. Error: ' + $_.Exception.Message
}
```

I had to put the catch line on the same line at the closing curly brace of the previous statement. Could not find anything a not sure why this is working for me. I tried by throwing an exception other than the one being caught, and the code works fine now.

I hope this can help other people experiencing the same.