# Why is the wrong catch exception type executed?

Tags: powershell, exception, catch-block

I initialize my function with two commands. First, I load a configuration file with `Get-Content` and secondly, I import a module (`Import-Module`).

```
try {
    Get-Content -Raw -Path Wrong-Path -ErrorAction Stop | ConvertFrom-Json
    Import-Module -Name Wrong_Module -Force -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException], [System.IO.FileNotFoundException]{
    "Catch block 1"
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]{
    "Catch block 2"
}
catch {
    "Catch block 3"
}
```

I tested both commands (`Get-Content and Import-Module`) on their exception type but I only the second catch block is run. However, actually both commands throw an exception which should trigger the first Catch-Block.

**Why is the wrong Catch-Exception block triggered?**

Comment: This is probably because the ItemNotFoundException class inherits the RuntimeException class. I can't bet my life on it though. If you reorder the catches or remove the RuntimeException exception condition, the result changes.

Comment: This appears to be a bug where `catch` clauses are not actually evaluated in order as advertised. PowerShell 6 behaves differently here and hits the first block; PowerShell 5.1 will only do so if the second block is omitted. (Both will ignore the third block if a more specific one applies.)

Comment: It looks like it is due to the -ErrorAction Stop flag.

Please refer to this answer and it's comment.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6780143/511105